# Install ffmpegthumbnalier on Elastic Beanstalk instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ffmpegthumbnailer

I need to install `ffmpegthumbnailer` to create video thumbnails in my Easltic Beanstalk instances. When I try to put in configuration in the .ebextensions directory under: packages => yum => ffmpegthumbnailer it comes back with an error. 
`No package ffmpegthumbnailer available.`

I tried add the `ffmpeg-devel` in the packages and then tried the `rpm` option. That came back with an error as well.

Please let me know if someone has done this successfully in the past. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This will be caused by yum running on the EB workers not being configured to use the nux-dextop repo.

Your best bet might be to package your application in a Docker image and deploying that. This will give you a lot more control over what packages you're able to install and gives you the ability to encapsulate all dependences in one place.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to easily install FFmpeg on Elastic Beanstalk from source a few years ago.  Here are my notes on that installation.  Please update the release for FFmpeg, as it looks like version 4.2 is the current stable version now. Here is the [FFmpeg download page](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

You can install from source by creating a configuration file in the `.ebextensions` folder:

```
# .ebextensions/ffmpeg.config

packages:
  yum:
    autoconf: []
    automake: []
    cmake: []
    freetype-devel: []
    gcc: []
    gcc-c++: []
    git: []
    libtool: []
    make: []
    nasm: []
    pkgconfig: []
    zlib-devel: []
sources:
  /usr/local/src: http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.2.tar.bz2
commands:
  ffmpeg_install:
    cwd: /usr/local/src/ffmpeg-3.2
    command: sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
```

The `packages` line of this file
tells Elastic Beanstalk to install several packages through yum that are
dependencies of FFmpeg.  Next, the `sources` line instructs Elastic Beanstalk
to download and unzip the ffmpeg tarball into the `/usr/local/src` directory.
The `commands` line then tells Elastic Beanstalk to change into the newly
unpacked ffmpeg-3.2 directory, and configure and install FFmpeg.

Ordinarily it is a good practice to install packages from source into the
`/usr/local` directory. However, it's possible that the
default user that runs your application may not have `/usr/local` in
its `PATH`.  Installing `ffmpeg` in the `/usr` directory ensures it will be
available to the application in`/usr/bin`.  But you can update the installation directory by modifying the `--prefix` in the `configure` command as needed.